# Making a geom_bar from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

**Background**

I have a dataframe, `df`, of athlete injuries:

```
df <- data.frame(number_of_injuries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 number_of_people = c(73,52,43,12,7,2),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**The Problem**

I'd like to use `ggplot2` to make a bar chart or histogram of this simple data using `geom_bar` or `geom_histogram`. Important point: I'm pretty novice with `ggplot2`.

I'd like something where the x-axis shows bins of the number of injuries (`number_of_injuries`), and the y-axis shows the counts in `number_of_people`. Like this (from Excel):

[image]

**What I've tried**

I know this is the most trivial dang `ggplot` issue, but I keep getting errors or weird results, like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(number_of_injuries)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

Which yields:

[image]

I've been in the tidyverse reference website for an hour at this and I can't crack the code.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. You're welcome to post that as an answer but this question I'm sure has been asked so many times before that they'll mark it closed any minute now. Thank you Zheyuan Li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can cause confusion from time to time. If you already have "count" statistics, then do not count data using `geom_bar(stats = "count")` again, otherwise you simply get 1 in all categories. You want to plot those values as they are with `geom_col`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = number_of_injuries, y = number_of_people)) + geom_col()
```